# Unable to download aptitude on AWS through Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am trying to harden my instance on AWS by downloading the Aptitude software package through Ubuntu. This is according to  the steps listed in this website:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-harden-server/index.html

Typically, I would use apt-get, but I know that AWS uses yum instead. That being said, the aptitude software package is not found when using yum.

Does anyone know that installing aptitude is possible? If so, how?

Comment: Can you paste your output of `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a`, and `hostnamectl`?  Also, what package are you trying to download with aptitude?

Comment: @dps I am currently logged into my instance. lsb_release and hostnamectl are both not recognised commands. However uname -a gives the following result: Linux ip-172-31-17-19 4.14.154-99.181.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Nov 16 01:38:34 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What exactly from this doc are you trying to install? You need to enable the EPEL repo to install tripwire.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/